# Finding an edge by unique ID or name

Tags: graph, graphviz, edge-list

It is possible to search a subgraph and node by their unique names;

```
n = agnode(g, "myUniqueNodeName", FALSE);
h = agsubg(g, "myUniqueSubgrahName", FALSE);
```

Likewise, is there a way to search edges in a strict directed graph by their unique names?

```
e = agedge (g, u, v, "e28", FALSE);
```

Documentation indicates that:

> The 'name'  of an edge (more correctly, identifier) is treated as a
>   unique indentifier for edges between a particular node pair. That is,
>   there can only be at most one edge with name e28 between any given u
>   and v, but there can be many other edges between other nodes.

It seems that there must be a list of edges that can be searched by name. Otherwise, a separate (ID -> edge) map will need to be maintained separately.